# How do I improve the number detection for blueprints (OCR)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr

I have a number of blueprints where I would like to detect the numbers on the blueprint such that I can turn them into proper models.
for example I have the following image[image: blueprint] and would like all the numbers on this image so I ran the following code:

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('vdb7C.jpg')

custom_config = r' (--oem 2 --psm 10'
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img,config=custom_config,lang='eng', output_type=Output.DICT)

n_boxes = len(d['level'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    text=d["text"][i]
    print(text+ str(str.isdigit(text)))
    if str.isdigit(text):
        (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)


cv2.imwrite("output.jpg" , img)
```

This gave me the following result: [image: output]. As you can see it does correctly identify a number of numbers on the blueprint, however it misses quite a few others and falsely detect a few that aren't really there. I care more about getting all the numbers than a few false positives but would still like to keep those to a minimum so any suggestions there?

I have already tried thinning operations, re-scaling the images, rotating the images and smoothing the images but all of those don't appear to make much difference, extreme rescaling (*0.1 or *10) does change a few things but any gains made in one part of the image are undone by faults appearing in other parts.

Especially difficult are situations such as on the left building where we have lines numbers close to or even overlapping part of the design.
Here we see 2 examples of such situations
[image: prolem2]
[image: prolem1]

also note that font usage is not consistent between images.

It's worth noting that the lines are almost always obviously thinner then the fond used for the numbers so perhaps something could be done with that?

I have also tried using the EAST OCR system with the following code:
img = cv2.imread('vdb7C.jpg')

```
W=5664
H=4000
dim = (W, H)
img = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("frozen_east_text_detection.pb")
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1.0, (W, H),
(123.68, 116.78, 103.94), swapRB=True, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
(scores, geometry) = net.forward(["feature_fusion/Conv_7/Sigmoid",
"feature_fusion/concat_3"])
(numRows, numCols) = scores.shape[2:4]
rects = []
confidences = []
# loop over the number of rows
for y in range(0, numRows):
    # extract the scores (probabilities), followed by the geometrical
    # data used to derive potential bounding box coordinates that
    # surround text
    scoresData = scores[0, 0, y]

    xData0 = geometry[0, 0, y]
    xData1 = geometry[0, 1, y]
    xData2 = geometry[0, 2, y]
    xData3 = geometry[0, 3, y]
    anglesData = geometry[0, 4, y]
    for x in range(0, numCols):

        if scoresData[x] < confidence:
            continue

        (offsetX, offsetY) = (x * 4.0, y * 4.0)

        angle = anglesData[x]
        cos = np.cos(angle)
        sin = np.sin(angle)

        h = xData0[x] + xData2[x]
        w = xData1[x] + xData3[x]

        endX = int(offsetX + (cos * xData1[x]) + (sin * xData2[x]))
        endY = int(offsetY - (sin * xData1[x]) + (cos * xData2[x]))
        startX = int(endX - w)
        startY = int(endY - h)

        rects.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))
        confidences.append(scoresData[x])
    boxes = non_max_suppression(np.array(rects), probs=confidences)
    for box in boxes:
        (y,h,x,w) = box
        print(box)
        print(np.shape(img))
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg" , img)
```

however this causes quite a number of bounding boxes to be outside of the image and in general the bounding boxes seem unrelated to the content, so anyone know what's up there?
Any suggestions? I have 8000 images right now and need to eventually process a total of about 400k images.

Comment: Any suggestions are welcome (even just criticism of my code style), if you have any questions please leave a comment so I can improve the question.

Comment: interesting project. I think yxour code is a bit short to properly detect stuff. See some of these tutorials https://www.pyimagesearch.com/category/optical-character-recognition-ocr/

Comment: @user3732793 thanks for the link, I'm going to look through these for suggestions

Comment: Do you want just a simple list of all the numbers? I am not sure how that is useful. If you extract all the numbers in the blueprint, how are you planning on mapping them back to the model? (how are you planning on identifying, for example, that a number came from the top left wall of a building)?

Comment: @Ananda I want the numbers plus their bounding boxes, I already have a system that creates a model without the numbers, so after I have the numbers I can building a simple machine learning system that snaps the most likely candidate to the appropriate length.

Comment: For text and line drawings: Please consider using lossless compression like png instead of jpg.

Comment: @MadMike unfortunately the data doesn't exist in .png form in most cases, the majority of the data is .jpg, I don't think that's reversible.

Comment: You can try this: 1. Convert the image to monochrome (cv2.threshold). 2. Find the skeleton of the image ( skeletonize() from skimage.morphology). 3. Use cv2.matchTemplate() whith mask. Templates is skeleton images of digit. Mask is dilate  skeleton images of digit.

Comment: @AlexAlex there are a few fonts in use, so I don't think that will work

Comment: remove lines which are larger then the higth or width of a number

Comment: @Dieter ooh that's a good idea, I can probably do that with houghlinestransform, however I think that the "empty space" created by this would still render the character unreadable to tesserect? Unless there is a way to eliminate those pixels?

Comment: @Thijser - is this only for one image? or do you need a general approach? + how manny images do you've?Is it okey to get the values, from 1 image within 1 minute? or does it has to be in matter of seconds?

Comment: @Dieter I currently have 8000 images, but eventually I'm expecting around 400 000 images, so I do need a bit of a general method, a few missed numbers in a few images is acceptable but right now it's missing around half of all numbers. I can however take a bit of time for each image, 1 minute or even 5 minutes is ok (we can scale into the cloud).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a solution that applies neural networks like [keras-ocr](https://github.com/faustomorales/keras-ocr) which applies CRAFT and CRNN. It does a better job in detecting text that overlaps with the design. This is what I got using it out of the box:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras_ocr

detector = keras_ocr.detection.Detector()

image = keras_ocr.tools.read('vdb7C.jpg')
boxes = detector.detect(images=[image])[0]
canvas = keras_ocr.tools.drawBoxes(image, boxes)
plt.imshow(canvas)
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run your `tesseract` piece of code, but only use results with 3 or more digits. This should provide you with enough good examples of digits. Extract each digit to separate file and save their positions. Now you can go two ways.

You can go the simple way if you will see that the fonts of the digits are quite similar. Then you can create a set of templates for the digits (say 15-30). Remember that you can get the size of the digits for specific image? Resize your digits template to the right size and run the most trivial template matching. This will definitely create some false detections (especially for "1"s), and you will have to find a way to reduce their amount to acceptable level.

More complex way is to build a custom CNN detector and train it on your data. So from the first stage you will get several hundred examples of digits (and their positions) that you want to detect. You can look at this [project](https://github.com/penny4860/Yolo-digit-detector) or this [one](https://github.com/penny4860/SVHN-deep-digit-detector) as references. Also this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-a-custom-object-detection-model-with-yolo-v5-917e9ce13208) can provide you some guidance.

One more thing that can be useful. Your images have lots of long perpendicular lines. If you align them to the axis, you can remove the lines very easily by binarizing the original, shifting the result (right or down) by several pixels and ANDing them. This will left only the long lines. Find their length, and you will be able to remove lines above certain length in the original image.

Comment: The method of removing lines seems like a good plan, one thing that does however worry me is that sometimes the lines go trough the values, if that happens won;t your method result in a gap appearing in the values? Does tesserect accept non continues numbers or do I have to somehow repair them (possibly by checking if the line pixels touch non line pixels)?

Comment: Yes, it will create gaps. Yes, Tesseract is capable of detecting characters with small gaps. For larger gaps (thick lines) you can restore the gap. Just scan the below and above the removed (horizontal) line, if you get that there are black pixels both above and below,  connect them. My intent of using this method was to reduce false detections of "1" on the vertical lines when using template matching, not as much to clean the image.